# How to set Default Value for a Map attribute of an item in Items.xml Hybris?

Tags: attributes, default-value, sap-commerce-cloud, items

I need to initialize a maptyped attribute of a item with defaultvalues of map.

lets say that we have defined a maptype

`<maptype code="dummyMap" argumenttype="java.lang.String" returntype="java.lang.String" autocreate="true" generate="false" />`

and we have declared a itemtype as

```
<itemtype code="dummyItem" autocreate="true" ...>
  <attributes>
    <attribute qualifier="dummyAttribute" type="dummyMap">
        <defaultvalue>???</defaultvalue>  <<<<<========= How should we initialize ?????
    </attribute>
  </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

As an example in similar case for an enum type attribute we define the default Value as

```
<defaultvalue>em().getEnumerationValue("dummyEnum","dummyEnum_Value")</defaultvalue>
```

How do we apply the same for a Maptyped attribute. Please let me know on how to initiale the attribute with a map value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latset version of Hybris, you can try passing a `java.util.Collections.singletonMap` e.g.

```
<defaultvalue>java.util.Collections.singletonMap("one", java.math.BigDecimal.ONE)</defaultvalue>
```

When I tested it with Hybris v1811 (as shown below),

```
<items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="items.xsd">

    <maptypes>
        <maptype code="DummyMap"
                 argumenttype="java.lang.String"
                 returntype="java.math.BigInteger"
                 autocreate="true"
                 generate="false"/>
    </maptypes>
    <itemtypes>
        <itemtype code="DummyItem" autocreate="true">
            <deployment table="DummyItem" typecode="30001" />
            <attributes>
                <attribute qualifier="uname" type="java.lang.String">
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" initial="true" optional="false"/>
                    <defaultvalue>"Hello"</defaultvalue>
                    <persistence type="property"></persistence>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="dummyAttribute" type="DummyMap">
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" initial="true" optional="false"/>
                    <defaultvalue>java.util.Collections.singletonMap("one", java.math.BigDecimal.ONE)</defaultvalue>
                    <persistence type="property"></persistence>
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
        </itemtype>
    </itemtypes>
</items>
```

the **XML Representation** of `DummyItem` in the **backoffice** showed:

```
<itemtype code="DummyItem" extends="GenericItem" jaloclass="org.training.jalo.DummyItem" generate="true" singleton="false" jaloonly="false" autocreate="true">
    <deployment table="dummyitem" typecode="30001"/>
    <attributes>
        <attribute generate="true" autocreate="true" qualifier="dummyAttribute" type="DummyMap"><!-- could not export defaultvalue '{one=1}' -->

            <persistence type="property" qualifier=""/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" encrypted="false" optional="false" removable="true" initial="true" unique="false" private="false" partof="false"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute generate="true" autocreate="true" qualifier="uname" type="java.lang.String">
            <defaultvalue>
new java.lang.String( "Hello" )
            </defaultvalue>
            <persistence type="property" qualifier=""/>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" encrypted="false" optional="false" removable="true" initial="true" unique="false" private="false" partof="false"/>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

As you can see, it was able to pass `new java.lang.String( "Hello" )` as the default value for the attribute, `uname` but for the attribute, `dummyAttribute`, it shows, `<!-- could not export defaultvalue '{one=1}' -->`.